# Download CSV from shopware 6 administration

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-api

I want to implement a CSV export from Shopware 6 admin. I have a button, want to open a new window and get a CSV file.

I implemented a controller:

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *     "/api/winkelwagen/export/csv/{id}",
 *     methods={"GET"},
 *     defaults={"auth_required"=true, "_routeScope"={"api"}}
 * )
 */
public function export(string $id, Context $context, Request $request): Response
{
    /** @var PromotionEntity $promo */
    $response->setContent('csv file');

    return $response;
}
```

But to call this controller, you need to be logged in which totally make sense.

My button in the administration currently opens a new window and opens the page:

```
window.open('http://www.fabian-blechschmidt.de', '_blank');
```

Which of course doesn't work with the api url, because you needs to be authenticated.

So my question is: How do I implement this authentication and get a CSV file in the backend? :-)

Maybe my approach is totally broken - happy to get a better idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend on the answer from dneustadt, the code snippet below also actually downloads the csv as a file by loading the data into a data url and clicking it virtually.

```
const initContainer = Shopware.Application.getContainer('init');
initContainer.httpClient.get(
    `winkelwagen/export/csv/${id}`,
    {
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/vnd.api+json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${Shopware.Service('loginService').getToken()}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    },
).then((response) => {
    if (response.data) {
        const filename = response.headers['content-disposition'].split('filename=')[1];
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
        link.download = filename;
        link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
        link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in http client and set the bearer token for authentication:

```js
const initContainer = Shopware.Application.getContainer('init');
initContainer.httpClient.get(
    `winkelwagen/export/csv/${id}`,
    {
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/vnd.api+json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${Shopware.Service('loginService').getToken()}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    },
);
```

Change the headers according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

dneustadt is a great start!
But Rune Laenen's answer is gold!

But I think due to the fact, that I don't return JSON but a CSV file, I needed to change a few things.

- For some reason the filename contained `"` as prefix and suffix - we cut these.
- The response.data is neither a file nor a Blob, which is needed for `URL.createObjectURL`  - no problem, we just make one.
- and the link doesn't seem to be attached to document, so we make sure no error is thrown

```js
     if (response.data) {
        let filename = response.headers['content-disposition'].split('filename=')[1];
        filename = filename.substring(1, filename.length - 1);
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data], {type: response.headers['content-type']}));
        link.download = filename;
        link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
        try {
            link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
        } catch (e) {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend to create a link with a data object on the fly. I believe this can create issues with large downloads (but I just assume).

I would suggest to do it like the core and use the access token.

See here https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/469a7fc7c7a60eea6ae0863f54cb489bc0cbf31c/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/core/service/api/import-export.api.service.js#L82